# BlocSelector usage

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

In bloc 7.2.0, What is the usage of `BlocSelector` ? I need a practical example for this widget.

```
BlocSelector<BlocA, BlocAState, SelectedState>(
  selector: (state) {
    // return selected state based on the provided state.
  },
  builder: (context, state) {
    // return widget here based on the selected state.
  },
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer could be found in the documentation:

> BlocSelector is a Flutter widget which is analogous to BlocBuilder but
> allows developers to filter updates by selecting a new value based on
> the current bloc state. Unnecessary builds are prevented if the
> selected value does not change. The selected value must be immutable
> in order for BlocSelector to accurately determine whether builder
> should be called again.

`BlocSelector` is the optimised version of the default `BlocBuilder`. When the state changes, `BlocBuilder` always triggers an update of your UI. However, with `BlocSelector` you could optimise this and trigger the UI rebuild only when the specific field/property of your state changes. Meaning, despite that the state is different if your selected property remains the same, the UI won't be rebuilt.